# What happened to the kid?

Tags: plot-explanation, mad-max-fury-road

I just realized I have no idea if the movie resolved this: In Mad Max Fury Road, one of Immortan Joe's main motivations is getting back the woman who is pregnant with his child(s).

Later in the movie she dies and the war boys cut her open (do a postmortem C-section), "finding" two babies, one of which is dead instantly, but the other is a perfectly healthy boy.

**What happened to Immortan Joe's newborn son at the end of the movie?**

I don't remember seeing him again and I don't think he was mentioned later. Did he die during the final battle?

Comment: SPOILER TAGS EXIST FOR A REASON *SIGH*

Comment: We have a clear [policy regarding spoilers](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I specifically did not include any spoilers in the title or the excerpt. Why would you even read the question if you haven't seen the movie?

Comment: Which movie? I've seen a lot of movies where a lot of things happen to kids, and only after I'd read the top line of the question did I realise it, but by then I'd also skimmed the next couple of lines.

However, just re-reading the spoiler policy I'm not sure if it would be valid to put the film title in the question. Apologies if I caused offense with my unthinking comment!

Comment: Here on the site we tag all questions with the name of the movie, so you could avoid that in the future by checking the tags first (which is a good idea for understanding the question anyway). You can even add movies to your tag ignore list until you have seen them, so that questions about them don't show up for you at all. Either way, I am sorry you got spoiled.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have misinterpreted the scene in question. Immortan Joe's wife (who I believe is referred to as "Splendid" in the film) was only pregnant with one child - a boy who dies around about the same time as his mother.

The man who attempts to perform a C-section on "Splendid" tells Rictus (one of Immortan Joe's other sons) that he would have had a baby brother who was "perfect in every way", had it it been one month later - not that he DOES have a baby brother.